# Source code (DOM) doesn't update after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to generate dynamic html content with php and jQuery (1.11).
It works but updates don't appear in source code and i'm worry about that because i think it's not good for search engines. For example, i can't test structured data (schema.org) on google tools.

**index.php**

```
<script>

    function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: CalRoot+"/events-by-agenda.php",
            data: "show=" + numRecords + "&pagenum=" + pageNum,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.loader').show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").html(data);
                $('.loader').hide();
            }
        });
        $(function() {
            $(".pagination").click(function() {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".contentDescription").offset().top
                }, 2000, 'swing');
            });
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        displayRecords(20, 1);
    });

</script>
```

**HTML section of index.php**

```
<div id="results"></div>
            <div class="loader"></div>
```

> events-by-agenda.php contains mysql query, results in html and
>   pagination

I read a lot of things about this, event delegation, use context(this), add .on method on a button for example but nothing works

Comment: Right, that's how ajax works. If the crawler isn't running javascript (some do), nothing you do with javascript is going to be read.

Comment: Modifying the DOM doesn't change the source code, just like editing a file in Word doesn't change the file until you save it.

Comment: @KevinB why source code is modified in this example (https://pushstate.search-foresight.com/), click on Nantes tab

Comment: What are you calling source code?

Comment: @KevinB the source viewed by the browsers, my goal is to be correctly view by google bots for pages of my pagination

Comment: Well, no, I mean what are you looking at in your browser that you think is the source? Because, what your saying is happening isn’t possible. The source cannot be changed by the browser. You can view the source right clicking on any page and clicking “view source” what you see in the dom inspector is *not* the source.